# How to get current year and add goal year of between 2 and 50 years

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a React hooks component with an input and the value returns the years that I will add to the current calendar year.

I have a function that I'm trying to create that would give me the current year and then add input value to that date:

```
<input value={input} handleChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}/>

const getYearDate = () => {
        const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
        let input = e.target.value;

        for (let i = currentYear; i <= 50; i++) {
            return currentYear + input[i]
        }

        return
    }
```

For example if the current year is 2020 and I add 2 years it should return 2022 if I add 30 years it should return 2050

Now I'm not sure if I can just use a reduce function that will add to the  currentYear?

I know I'm doing it wrong. Any ideas of how I can improve and get the result that I need?

Comment: Your example and problem statement aren't quite clear - are you looking for a range of values from 2 to 50 years? Or, are you looking for a single value with respect to current year? And what's the condition for adding 2 or 50 to it?

Comment: I'm looking for a single value in respect to current year. So if the user puts in 5 years, then the newYear gets added to the current year. What I'm not sure of is if that's more of a reduce function or if I'm looping through based on the user's input of the year.

Comment: Then, it should be simple as just adding the value to the current year part. Check the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. You'll pass a date and number of years that you want to add.

```js
function add_years(dt, n) {
  return new Date(dt.setFullYear(dt.getFullYear() + n));
}

dt = new Date();
console.log(add_years(dt, 10).toString());

dt = new Date(2014, 10, 2);
console.log(add_years(dt, 10).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var currentYear = new Date();
currentYear.setFullYear(currentYear.getFullYear() + yearToAdd);
```

Example (You can edit yearToAdd... idk how you choose it):

```js
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();   
var yearToAdd = 2;
currentYear += yearToAdd;
console.log(currentYear);
```